# Setting Rasp Pi screen resolution remotely for remote access

Tags: linux, display

I have a Raspberry Pi that I am accessing via Screen Connect for remote access. Is there a way to set the pi so that when it boots up it uses a specific screen resolution?

Editing the HDMI settings did not seem to fix this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to force HDMI with this setting `hdmi_force_hotplug=1` in `/flash/config.txt`, and it will use your display settings.

config.txt may be in `boot/` if you do not have `flash/`

Answer (score 0):

On your pi's terminal you can run the command

```
sudo raspi-config
```

Once you see the raspi-config box, use the "arrow keys" to select

`7 Advanced Options`, `Enter`
Then select `A5 Resolution`

From there, you can change the resolution. I changed mine to mode 85.

Once you've finished making your changes, use the `Tab` key to `OK` the changes.

Comment: That did not work for me when I was remotely connected. When I select the Resolution Menu the selection jumps back to the main menu.

Answer (score 0):

as stated above you can use
"sudo raspi-config" go to [advanced options], then select a new resolution, restart.

then will also need to then select it in preferences - screen configuration.